# No sound (dummy output) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with external speakers

Tags: sound, 20.04, speakers, output

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Dell Inspiron 530. I purchased some external speakers that were working just fine with my machine, but for some reason, now I'm only getting Dummy Output as an output device. I've tried everything included in [this post](https://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1304-quick-tip/) to try and fix the problems with no luck. I've also tried both the front and back port for the 3.5mm speaker output. Still nothing. Headphones also aren't recognized.

Here's my output from `pacmd list-sources`:

```
1 source(s) available.
  * index: 0
    name: <auto_null.monitor>
    driver: <module-null-sink.c>
    flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY DYNAMIC_LATENCY
    state: IDLE
    suspend cause: (none)
    priority: 1000
    volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
            balance 0.00
    base volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
    volume steps: 65537
    muted: no
    current latency: 0.00 ms
    max rewind: 16 KiB
    sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    channel map: front-left,front-right
                 Stereo
    used by: 0
    linked by: 0
    configured latency: 2000.00 ms; range is 0.50 .. 2000.00 ms
    monitor_of: 0
    module: 13
    properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Dummy Output"
        device.class = "monitor"
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
```

my output for `inxi -A`

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel 82801I HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel 
  Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-40-generic
```

and my output for `lspci -v | grep -i audio`

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 02)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did this speaker system ever work with the Dell? If yes, which OS? Does your headphone work? What is the output of `pacmd --list-sources`. The post you're refering to is rather a summary of solutions to different problems - none of them you have. Edit your question and add the missing infos

Comment: @kanehekili done

Comment: Thanks - "Dummy Output" means "I don't have any idea about your audio card". So a driver is missing. Linix can't communicate with it. `inxi -A`would tell us, which card exists, or you could use `lspci -v | grep -i audio`to enlighten us...

Comment: @kanehekili i updated my post with the info

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I've played around a little and could fake what you've got: a dummy monitor only.
So I achieved that by playing around with the pavuControl, which is the GUI to pulse audio.
If all profiles are turned off, you won't have any sound, so I've turned them on again:

[image]

Now my list-sources is much longer. So install `pavucontrol`, ignore the Gnome sound settings and try to fix your sound. Because your card should work.

In addition check if your pulseaudio is running:

```
systemctl --user status pulseaudio
```

and take a look at the logs:

```
journalctl | grep pulseaudio
```

Since the latter command displays the whole log, check the date, it might start from some months ago.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my father's computer (also a Dell Inspiron 530) via adding the following to the end of `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
set-card-profile alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1b.0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
set-sink-port alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo analog-output-lineout
```

This works around an issue -- on the first line -- where the card profile isn't properly set, and -- on the second line -- where the card defaults to headphones instead of speakers.